# I want to play music in my site and music should keep playing even if i go to other page in my site

Tags: wordpress-theming

I want to play music in my site and music should keep playing even if i go to other page in my site. How can i do it in worpdress.
I want to do something like this following songs play side does. https://soundcloud.com/

Comment: I think those make use of frame or iframe?

Comment: Please never ever put background music in a site.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you : Use this plugin to play background music .. https://wordpress.org/plugins/background-music-player-lite/